# How does the state trie stored in database (leveldb)?

Tags: merkle-patricia-tries, state-trie, leveldb

ive read the articles published about state trie, and how data are stored in ethereum and such but i am still not clear how the state trie are stored in database like in leveldb.
Ive got a couple of question.

a. the blockheader contains he root hash of the state trie, but how does the chain server code rebuild the tree from this hash?

b. Does the server stores the hash of every node whether its a branch, leaf, extension, in the the database and it is rebuilt from there?
That means every changes in the tree only the new nodes are added in the database?